# nodeJS: io is not defined error on frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku

When I run my nodejs app with nodemon on localhost, on the frontend-side, `socket.io` is not being displayed and if I put `/socket.io/socket.io.js` at the end of the url, no socket library is displayed. The error I get is as follows:
[Chrome Debug Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FPIg.png)

I have set-up the `socket.io` on the server and client side of the code and have installed the packages.

Is this a declaration error of socket.io in the code, or a system error of socket.io? [I'm using localhost and Heroku]

EDIT:
Changed the syntax error in `index.html` file and changed `app.listen` to `server.listen`.

[New Chrome Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mTR.png)

---

server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User was disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(port , () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

---

index.html(client-side):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <p>Welcome to the chat app</p>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to server');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Disconnected from server');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.8.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the html file. Replace this line :

```
<script> src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

That what the "SyntaxError: unexpected end of input" reveals from your screenshot.

Comment: Okay. However, when I do the edit, I get a new error. Pic above ^